# rename tag [mac-osx] to [macOS] in alignment with the official name from Apple

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed

Please rename tag `[mac-osx]` to `[macOS]` in alignment with the official name. It seems I don't have the permissions for that action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Done - this seems uncontroversial. Seems tags can't be capitalised so the end result was [macos](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/macos).